# How to get latest package version with Ansible

Tags: ansible, yum

I'm trying to replicate the command `yum check-update package_name` preferably with the Ansible `yum` module.

It provides an information to what version package would be updated after `yum update` execution (or ansible equivalent). For example:

```
root@host: $ yum check-update kernel
[...]
kernel.x86_64                                                    3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7
[...]
root@host: $
```

I tried various combination of

```yaml
- name: Xyz
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    list: updates
    update_cache: true
```

But I can't limit it to a single package or pattern (like `java*`).

What I ended up with is ugly and slow (because of the download) workaround:

```yaml
- name: Check latest available xyz version
  yum:
    name: xyz
    state: latest
    download_only: true
  become: true
  register: _result

- name: Register xyz version
  set_fact:
    latestXyz: "{{ _result.changes.updated[0][1] | regex_search('xyz-(.+).x86_64.*', '\\1') }}"
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: To get a better understanding of your use case, can you describe in more detail why it necessary to check available version numbers before rather than just defining the desired state, in example latest? Or just updating?

Comment: It is pretty simple use case.  It was required for a playbook to display current and latest version of the package and then ask whether update it or not. Nothing fancy :)

Comment: "_... and then ask whether update it or not_" which seems not to be real automation and / or configuration management because it depends then on a human, on human interaction and someone has to do something manual (answering a question) based on whatever rules which are definded somehow somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pretty easy way to achieve this is to run the `yum` module as you would to update the package, but enforce a dry run on it, with the [`check_mode` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks), and register the result of this task.

Inspecting the result, you'll realise that the module will list you the current version of the package and the version it would have been updated to, would it not have been run in dry run.

Given, for example

```yaml
- yum:
    name: expat
    state: latest
  check_mode: true
  register: yum_latest_versions
```

Will populate the variable `yum_latest_versions` on a `fedora:35` container with:

```yaml
yum_latest_versions:
  ansible_facts:
    pkg_mgr: dnf
  changed: true
  failed: false
  msg: 'Check mode: No changes made, but would have if not in check mode'
  rc: 0
  results:
  - 'Installed: expat-2.5.0-1.fc35.x86_64'
  - 'Removed: expat-2.4.9-1.fc35.x86_64'
```

Then to extract, you can indeed use a regex to search in the result:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        (
          yum_latest_versions.results
            | map('regex_search', '^Installed: expat\-(.*)\.x86_64$', '\1')
        ).0.0
      }}
```

Finally yields:

```yaml
msg: 2.5.0-1.fc37
```

Comment: Idk how I missed this option. It works blazing fast now. 
Thank you so much.